# Wordpress imageg cropping when upload

Tags: wordpress

The image cropping option code not working for me, I tried below code

```
add_image_size( 'featured-image', 2000, 1200 );
```

for crop images when I upload.
but not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, you can try this code for hard crop in left top

```
add_image_size( 'custom-size', 220, 220, array( 'left', 'top' ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

First off you should really use an action hook to do this. In regards to the question, if you want the image to be cropped to the exact size, you have to add `true` to the end of the function. Otherwise wordpress will just resize it the best it can.

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpdocs_theme_setup' );
function wpdocs_theme_setup() {
    add_image_size( 'featured-image', 2000, 1200, true );
}
```

Here is the specification for this wordpress function.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
add_image_size( 'featured-image', 2000, 1200, true );
```